# remove WYSIWYG editor but keep media button

Tags: tinymce

i need to remove the deafault TinyMCE editor from pages, i used this:

```
remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
```

But it removes also the media button that i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the brand new wp_editor function in WP3.3, there's an option tiny_mce=true/false:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor